# In C#, how can a derived manager class return instances of a derived class without re-implementing everything?

Tags: c#, oop

In the example below, how can I get SpecialThingDB to return a List of SpecialThings without having to re-implement all of ThingDB's methods as I have done?

```
public class Thing
{
    public readonly string Color;
    public readonly int Weight;

    public Thing(string color, int weight)
    {
        Color = color;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    // Some methods
}

public class ThingDB
{
    public List<Thing> GetByColor(string color)
    {
        var things = new List<Thing>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return things;
    }

    public List<Thing> GetByWeight(int weight)
    {
        var things = new List<Thing>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return things;
    }
}

public class SpecialThing : Thing
{
    public SpecialThing(string color, int weight) : base(color, weight)
    {
    }

    // Some special methods
}

public class SpecialThingDB : ThingDB
{
    // How do I have GetByColor and GetByWeight return SpecialThings here
    // without completely re-implementing the base methods like below?

    public List<SpecialThing> GetByColor(string color)
    {
        var specialThings = new List<SpecialThing>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return specialThings;
    }

    public List<SpecialThing> GetByWeight(int weight)
    {
        var specialThings = new List<SpecialThing>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return specialThings;
    }
}
```

Also, is there a better pattern other than having two classes (one representing one record and the other being a manager class) for every table in my database?

**UPDATE**

Given the solution (thanks, the_joric!), here is what I've changed about the above code:

```
public class ThingDB<T> where T : Thing
{
    public List<T> GetByColor(string color)
    {
        var things = new List<T>();
        // Do some database stuff to fill things by color
        return things;
    }

    public List<T> GetByWeight(int weight)
    {
        var things = new List<T>();
        // Do some database stuff to fill things by weight
        return things;
    }
}

public class SpecialThing : Thing
{
    public SpecialThing(string color, int weight)
        : base(color, weight)
    {
    }

    // Some special methods
}

public class SpecialThingDB : ThingDB<SpecialThing> { }

public class ThingDB : ThingDB<Thing> { } // For backward-compatibility
```

Comment: maybe I don't understand you fully, but shouldn't `base.GetByColor(color).Cast<SpecialThing>()` work?

Comment: Possibly, but I want to be a DRY as possible and not re-implement each method in the derived class, even if that is just explicitly calling the base method with a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics. Like the following:

```
public class ThingDB<T> where T: Thing
{
    public List<T> GetByColor(string color)
    {
        var things = new List<T>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return things;
    }

    public List<T> GetByWeight(int weight)
    {
        var things = new List<T>();
        // Get things from the database's Thing table
        return things;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So can I also add `public class ThingDB : ThingDB<Thing> { }` to this solution so as not to break existing references to ThingDB?

Comment: Seems I have to add constructors to such a derived class [forehead slap], but beyond that, this seems to be working so far...

Answer (score 0):

Generics:

[the_joric beat me to it on this one]

Also: Probably, yes.  Use an object-relational mapper to do this for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

Comment: Yes, this is the output of a home-grown ORM (riiiiight...), a heavily-modded http://csharpdatatier.sourceforge.net/